# LWUIT: How to POST a form with HTMLComponent

Tags: java, forms, java-me, lwuit

I hava form that shows well, I can fill in all the labels, I have even overriden the textfield for easier input. but when I press the 'save' button to POST the form. All it does is reload the HTMLComponent.

Why is this and how do i do POST a form?

Comment: Can you post some of your html and java code? we can't do any thing with out it

Answer (score 2):

You need to point the form at an absolute URL and make sure you defined a DocumentRequestHandler that can handle HTTP. The DefaultDocumentRequestHandler in LWUIT doesn't know how to handle HTTP, you can use the AsyncDocumentRequestHandlerImpl from LWUIT4IO or get the DocumentRequestHandler code from the LWUIT browser.